# How to separate marshalled ecdsa public and private keys in GoLang

Tags: go, encryption, public-key-encryption, ecdsa

So far, I have:

```
key, err := ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P521(), rand.Reader)
if err != nil {
    os.Exit(-1)
}
marshalled, err := x509.MarshalECPrivateKey(key) // marshalls data to byte stream
if err != nil {
    os.Exit(-1)
}
```

Basically, what I am having trouble with has to do with the fact that when a key pair is generated, it is stored in an `*ecdsa.PrivateKey`, in which the public key is stored in the `*ecdsa.PrivateKey.PublicKey`, and when I marshall the key pair data (stored in the `*ecdsa.PrivateKey`) using `x509.MarshalECPrivateKey(key)`, a single byte slice is returned. I am therefore having trouble determining which are the public and private keys in the byte slice itself.

Answer (score 0):

The private key is a superset of the public key.  It always contains the public key.  Usually a public key is stored as part of a certificate.

If you really want to get the public key by itself, you can grab the `X` and `Y` big integers from the ecdsa public key struct and store the binary representation of them.

You might benefit from a bit of retrospect on your design here.  There aren't too many situations where you need to communicate a public key alone.

Comment: I need to do this, because I need to share the public key and keep the private key in secret, while both are in a binary representation.

Comment: Why are you not storing the public in a certificate?

Comment: How may I go about doing that? (No pun intended)

Comment: I suggest you give the `x509` package documentation a good read.